# Calling the property names of a dynamic property "ints": can't call property

Tags: c#, linq, expandoobject, idictionary

I am assigning property names of a dynamic object as ints in string form. The int value represents an int ID in a database I am using. However I am stuck on how to retrieve the value assigned to the property as shown below:

```
dynamic test = new ExpandoObject()
IDictionary<string, object> proxyFiler = test as IDictionary<string, object>;
proxyFiler["four"] = 4;
proxyFiler["5"] = 5;
int r = test.four; // Works
int s = test.5; // Doesn't work
```

A method which reads the database will return an "int" and I would like to be able to access the property value with that property name.

**To expand on this:** what if I wanted to do a linq query to sort out a list of dynamic objects according to a property name? In this case I need to get the propertyName which I have retrieved as a string e.g. "15":

```
 return disorderedList.OrderBy(o => o.propertyName).ToList();
```

Does anyone know a simple solution to this problem or do you recommend a different approach? Thanks.

Comment: Why would the second example work? `value` is unused.

Comment: Why do you have to say `test.5` instead of `proxyFiler["5"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for `dynamic` to work in this way, the key has to follow the rules for valid identifier names in C# (the rules are specified in this [outdated MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx), but also in the C# language specification).  A single number (`5`) is not an allowed identifier name, which is why that doesn't work.

Note that you *can* still retrieve the value by using the type as a dictionary, in a similar manner to how you populated it.

As for your second example - you are never using `value`, so it has no effect.  It's the same as just writing `int r = test.four;`

---

Edit:

I believe, given your approach, you'd need to cast to a dictionary:

```
return disorderedList
          .OrderBy(o => ((IDictionary<string, object>)o)[propertyName]).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Reed, do you think there is a way around the problem? I've edited the question to explain my problem better.

Comment: @Nic Just access it as a dictionary - the same way you store it

Comment: Thanks again @ReedCopsey. I have now expanded the question.

Comment: @Nic I believe what I posted will do what you want.

Comment: Actually @ReedCopsey, when trying to do what you suggested I get this error: "Additional information: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'"

Comment: @Nic I had a typo at one point - make sure to try the latest, since it should work (the cast happens before the indexer)

Comment: For simplicity, if I need to access the value of the property for multiple (identical in properties) dynamic objects maybe it would be a good idea to access the dynamic object properties by index. What do you guys think? @ReedCopsey